# error in LINQ while converting IPaddress to String using C# and PostgreSQL database

Tags: c#, linq, npgsql

How to convert IPAddress to String is not that enough to use .ToString()? 
I do it in LINQ and I get :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

here is my code:

```
 var x = (from t in db.v_vpn_gateway.AsEnumerable()

                 select new TurbineDvce
                 {
                     Comments = "VPN Gateway",
                     Description = string.Empty,
                     DeviceType = t.device_type,                                              
                     TurbineId = t.turbine_id.ToString(),
                     Username = string.Empty
                 })
```

TurbineId is string

Comment: Please, share a reproducible sample

Comment: because t.turbine_id is null so you can't add .ToString() Do a null check, then add .ToString

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: BTW why do you need `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @GuruStron in .Net Core i get an error stating multiple connection at the same time to database,then i found on the internet its better to apply the condition after converting to AsEnumerable

Comment: @mortezasol there should be no problems with having multiple connection at the same time to postgres. Conditions i general should not by applied after `AsEnumerable` cause `AsEnumerable` will fetch whole table into memory. As for projection - it depends on how many column you actually need.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks for the advice,but whats the reason its said,in .NetCore the query is done on the server side,so sometimes it has a problem with union and other conditions if you apply ,beuacse it cant transalte it on the server side,thats why it should be converted to AsEnumerable,whats your idea?

Comment: @mortezasol it was not evident from you example that you was resolving such problems. Have you tried the null check?

Comment: @GuruStron if i dont convert to AsEnumerable how should i check if its null or emtry,if its not null then convert it to string.

Comment: @mortezasol you will need to check, but i would say you will not need to, if db can handle conversion from type of  `turbine_id` to string(nvarchar) then it just will put nulls in your string.

Comment: @GuruStron you are right,but i dont have a control over the DB otherwise i would ask them(other team) to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214319/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-mortezasol).

Answer (score 0):

Because `t.turbine_id` is null so you can't add `.ToString()` Do a null check, then add `.ToString()`

```
TurbineId = t.turbine_id ?? t.turbine_id.ToString()
```

Comment: Since `AsEnumerable()` is called you can just `t.turbine_id?.ToString()`

Comment: ?? cant apply to operand IPAddress and string

Comment: So `TurbineId` is of what type?

Comment: its string but t.turbine_id is Ipadress

Comment: how should i check if IPaddress is null or empty?